# Critical Security Alert using Gmail SMTPClient in Xamarin Application

Tags: xamarin, smtpclient

I am developing a cross platform Xamarin application that uses Google's SMTPClient to send order confirmation emails in the app directly, following this tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-send-email-using-smtp2/

Emails have been sending without issues during the development of the app, while testing on only a couple of devices in house, but now that I go to release it to 20+ different devices with different IP addresses, none of the emails are sending and the app is crashing. When I login to the google account that is used to send the emails, I am confronted with: "Critical Security Alert. Suspicious attempt to sign in with your password", each time a crash occurred.

I have third party access enabled, but it seems like Google is still not allowing the user to send emails from new devices with new IP Addresses. How can I get around this?

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: use a third party service that is intended for e-mail distribution.  I suspect what you are doing is probably against GMail TOS

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response. I am considering switching to Mimekit/Mailkit - do you think it will work?

Comment: I don't think either of those are e-mail distribution services - you still have to supply an smtp server

Comment: What about using AWS Simple Email Service? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-send-email-using-aws-sessimple-email-service/

Comment: What about it?  Yes, that appears to be one of many different e-mail services you could potentially use.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, thanks for your time!